# wanted to play my sound file when notification event occurs and then stop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker, uilocalnotification

I am making an Alarm clock in which i want that when the selected time through Datepicker occur instead of only notification and Badge occurance , I wanted to play my custom Sound file i.e. jet.wav (it is of less than 30 sec and in .wav format).i want that as soon as my notification occurs it should play a sound and when i click on the app or alert view then it should stop. So can anyone please help me out. here is what i am trying :-

Code:-

```
@class The420DudeViewController;

@interface The420DudeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    The420DudeViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet The420DudeViewController *viewController;

extern NSString *kRemindMeNotificationDataKey;






@implementation The420DudeAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

NSString *kRemindMeNotificationDataKey = @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey";

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Application Delegate Methods ===
#pragma mark -



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls) {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:
                                             UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        if (notification) {
            NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo 
                                      objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
            [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
        }
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo
                              objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end




@interface The420DudeViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
    IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *selectTimePicker;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *selectTimePicker;

-(IBAction)onTapSetAlarm;
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text;

@end




@implementation The420DudeViewController

@synthesize titleBar,setAlarmButton,selectTimePicker;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Initialization and shutdown ===
#pragma mark -

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectTimePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.setAlarmButton = nil;
    self.selectTimePicker = nil;
}
/*
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Song1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
//  [player play];
}
 */
-(IBAction)onTapSetAlarm
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [selectTimePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    //  notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jet" ofType:@"wav"];
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Mayank"
                                                             forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }

/*
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];

NSDate *selectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
selectedDate = [selectTimePicker date];

NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:selectedDate];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Time selected" message:theTime delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
//  [timeFormat release];
//  [selectedDate release];

 */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Public Methods ===
#pragma mark -

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" 
                                                        message:@" TEXT " delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [titleBar release];
    [setAlarmButton release];
    [selectTimePicker release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName) for `soundName`, you should

> specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle

Thus I suggest you change this line of `-[The420DudeViewController onTapSetAlarm]`:

```
    notif.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jet" ofType:@"wav"];
```

to the following:

```
    notif.soundName = @"jet.wav";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am such a duffer actually.Do you know one more thing actually the alarm is not poping up at correct time.. it is delaying sometimes by 15 sec and sometimes by 50 sec...(random time not specific), do you any solution. it will be much appreciated.. :)